# How to use Multer without express

Tags: node.js, web-applications, multer

I am trying to set up image upload for a website with a node.js backend. I am sending the image file as a `FormData` object on a ajax post request. Can I use Multer without Express to upload the images? If so, how can I do it? (considering that I am not using express I have to manually collect post data)

Comment: What does this mean? Do you use plain Node `http` module?

Comment: yes, without express

Comment: You cannot use Multer without because it's Express middleware. It's based on Busboy so you can check how it uses it and use it directly.

Comment: In that case, would it be easier to do image uploading without any outside module or can I use Formidable as an alternative?

Comment: I can't say for sure but I'd try to use existing lib like Formidable first if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use multer, use [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) instead.
multer is only a wrapper around busboy to stick into express' middleware system. Multer is however not strcitly required to be used with express, it just is about to fit into express.

So you could use multer by writing some "unwrapping" code. But it is easier to use busboy without unwrapping the wrapping.

There are straightforward examples on the [busboy npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy).